# Using log4j json-event-layout with Karaf 3.0.5 running under servicemix

Tags: log4j, apache-karaf, karaf, apache-servicemix

I am trying to use [JSONEventLayoutV1](https://github.com/logstash/log4j-jsonevent-layout) as the pattern layout for karaf logging to log all events in json format.

The steps that I have followed.

1. Modified the `pom.xml` file of `jsonevent-layout` as shown below:-

   ```
   <plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.3.7</version>
   <extensions>true</extensions>
   <configuration>
       <instructions>
           <Bundle-Name>${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}</Bundle-Name>
           <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
           <Import-Package>*;resolution:=optional</Import-Package>
           <Export-Package>*</Export-Package>
           <Fragment-Host>org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-service;bundle-version="[1.6,1.7)"</Fragment-Host>
           <Embed-Dependency>*;scope=compile|runtime;inline=true</Embed-Dependency>
           <Implementation-Version>${project.version}</Implementation-Version>
       </instructions>
   </configuration>
   ```

   `</plugin>`
2. Build json format using `mvn clean install -Pbundle`
3. Copy bundle created to system directory

   ```
   mkdir -p ${karaf.home}/system/net/logstash/log4j/jsonevent-layout/1.8-SNAPSHOT/    
   cp target/jsonevent-layout-1.8-SNAPSHOT.jar ${karaf.home}/system/net/logstash/log4j/jsonevent-layout/1.8-SNAPSHOT/
   ```
4. Add this line to `etc/startup.properties` before Pax Logging 

   `net/logstash/log4j/jsonevent-layout/1.8-SNAPSHOT/jsonevent-layout-1.8-SNAPSHOT.jar=3
   mvn\:org.ops4j.pax.url/pax-url-aether/2.4.1 = 5
   mvn\:org.ops4j.pax.url/pax-url-wrap/2.4.1/jar/uber = 5
   mvn\:org.ops4j.pax.logging/pax-logging-api/1.8.4 = 8
   mvn\:org.ops4j.pax.logging/pax-logging-service/1.8.4 = 8`
5. Updated `org.ops4j.pax.logging.cfg` as follows:-

   `log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
   log4j.appender.stdout.layout=net.logstash.log4j.JSONEventLayoutV1
   log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} | %-5.5p | %-16.16t | %-32.32c{1} | %X{bundle.id} - %X{bundle.name} - %X{bundle.version} | %m%n`

But whenever I am starting Karaf I am getting the below exception:-

```
jabong@jabong1143:~/Downloads/software/dev/apache-servicemix-6.1.0$ sudo bin/servicemix
Please wait while Apache ServiceMix is starting...
 21% [===============>                                                        ]log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate class [net.logstash.log4j.JSONEventLayoutV1].
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.logstash.log4j.JSONEventLayoutV1 not found by org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-service [5]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1532)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:75)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1955)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:198)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.instantiateByClassName(OptionConverter.java:326)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.instantiateByKey(OptionConverter.java:123)
    at org.apache.log4j.PaxLoggingConfigurator.parseAppender(PaxLoggingConfigurator.java:129)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:735)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configureRootCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:615)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:502)
    at org.apache.log4j.PaxLoggingConfigurator.doConfigure(PaxLoggingConfigurator.java:72)
    at org.ops4j.pax.logging.service.internal.PaxLoggingServiceImpl.updated(PaxLoggingServiceImpl.java:214)
    at org.ops4j.pax.logging.service.internal.PaxLoggingServiceImpl$1ManagedPaxLoggingService.updated(PaxLoggingServiceImpl.java:362)
    at org.apache.felix.cm.impl.helper.ManagedServiceTracker.updated(ManagedServiceTracker.java:189)
    at org.apache.felix.cm.impl.helper.ManagedServiceTracker.updateService(ManagedServiceTracker.java:152)
    at org.apache.felix.cm.impl.helper.ManagedServiceTracker.provideConfiguration(ManagedServiceTracker.java:85)
    at org.apache.felix.cm.impl.ConfigurationManager$UpdateConfiguration.run(ConfigurationManager.java:1747)
    at org.apache.felix.cm.impl.UpdateThread.run(UpdateThread.java:103)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
log4j:ERROR No layout set for the appender named [out].
100% [========================================================================]
```

Can some one let me know what I am doing wrong?

The issue has also been discussed in [Karaf User Forum](http://karaf.922171.n3.nabble.com/Karaf-logging-in-JSON-format-td4045607.html). But still no luck.

Comment: check your import/export packages for this class/package.

Comment: @AchimNierbeck - I added `<Import-Package>*;resolution:=optional</Import-Package>` and `<Export-Package>*</Export-Package>` in pom.xml. But still getting the same error. Updated my `pom.xml` in the question as well.

Comment: as you already posted this on the karaf mailinglist, keep the communication there.

Answer (score 1):

The fragement approach is correct for plain log4j. Not sure if it also works for pax-logging. An approach that works is to offer a pax logging appender service and wrap the above appender in it. See [this code from karaf decanter](https://github.com/apache/karaf-decanter/tree/master/collector/log) as an example.

Depending on what you want to achieve it might be even easier to simply use [apache karaf decanter](https://github.com/apache/karaf-decanter). It can capture log messages jmx and system informations and push them among others into elastic search.

Comment: I am just trying to make karaf log all messages in json format. So for that I tried to use JSONEventLayout. Can you please let me know how can I achieve the same?

Comment: In decanter there currently is no appender for the json format. But you could implement a org.ops4j.pax.logging.spi.PaxAppender and publish as a service. Inside you could then feed into the json appender.

Comment: The fragment approach is one of the ways to add custom appenders to Pax-Logging. The issue here seems more like to be a correct import-package issue